# Remove only a part of a link with Lexical

Tags: lexicaljs

I am wondering if there is any easy way to remove only a part of a link with Lexical framework? https://lexical.dev/

For example, from the https://playground.lexical.dev/, is it possible to remove only the link on `repository` but keep the link on `Github`?

[image]

I am using this command to remove a link but it's removing the whole link, not on the text I selected:

```
editor.dispatchCommand(TOGGLE_LINK_COMMAND, null);
```

Thank you